# error: Json parsing in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

```
    file= File.read('customers.json')
data_hash= JSON.parse(  file)

 # id=data_hash['customers'].map { |x| x['id']  }
 data_hash['customers']['user_id'].each do |user|
        latitude=user['customers']['latitude']
        puts latitude
    end
```

what error I am facing?
 no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)

below is my json file

```
{
  "customers" :[
    {"latitude": "12.986375", "user_id": "12", "name": "Chris", "longitude": "77.043701"},
    {"latitude": "11.92893", "user_id": "1", "name": "Alice", "longitude": "78.27699"},
    {"latitude": "11.8856167", "user_id": "2", "name": "Ian", "longitude": "78.4240911"}
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your `data_hash`. Because it is a nested hash. So need to see it clearly

Comment: Could you show the `customers.json` file had? Or `file` value?

Comment: Then, what are you trying to do with the json? Are you trying to get a lists of latitude or something?

Comment: well, precisely i need latitude and longitude corresponding to each user_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to get `latitude` or something you should do it like:

```
file = File.read('customers.json')
data_hash = JSON.parse(file)

data_hash["customers"].each do |user|
  latitude = user["latitude"]
  puts latitude
end
```

OUTPUT:

```
12.986375
11.92893
11.8856167
```

Comment: @dv akhil, Welcome. Please accept the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)` error occurs when you try to treat an array as a hash. Since arrays expect integer keys for indexing Ruby will try to implicitly cast whatever gets passed to `[]` to an integer:

```
[]['a']
TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer
```

In your case it's the `data_hash['customers']` node that's an array.

You can actually just iterate through each item in `data_hash[`customers`]` mapping the value for the `:latitude` key back to an array via `map`.

```
puts data_hash["customers"].map { |h| h["latitude"] }
```

Comment: precisely i need latitude and longitude corresponding to each user_id

Comment: @dvakhil, why did you accept the anwer right here and the proper answer that you got is my answer?

Comment: @HashRocket sorry I am new to stack.